# Android Home button on custom title bar

Tags: android, title

I built home button on custom titlebar (use picture to button).
My Problem is every time to click this button. It will go to main.
When stay in main page and click the button. It will to main page again and again.
How I do?? 
I want it not go to main when stay main or Can't click this button in main page.

Are you understand?

Please help me
Thank you

```
public class CustomTitleBar extends Activity {
protected ImageButton toHome;
protected TextView title;
protected ImageView icon;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);

    toHome = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.header);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    icon  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

    ProgressBar titleProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadProgress);
    titleProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

    /* -- Button to HOME -- */
    toHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent goHome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            goHome.setClass(CustomTitleBar.this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(goHome);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

}
```

have people tell me to use finish(); but it can't fix my problem.

from example : main > page1 > (click home) > main > page2 > (click home) > main

when click back button on mobile

cycle is : main > page2 > main > page1 > main > out of app.

when click back button on mobile after I use finish();

cycle is : main > main > main > out of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when you navigate from sub page to home.
Here's my example code:

```
/* -- Button to HOME -- */
toHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent goHome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        goHome.setClass(CustomTitleBar.this, MainActivity.class);
        goHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(goHome);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much but How to use it?

Comment: Ha ha, it's: toHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

Comment: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MainActivity>) is undefined....

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've pasted, you have explicitly defined an an `intent` to go to the `MainActivity.class`. If you don't want the home button to go back to your "mainactivity" then you need to define a different intent. Otherwise, paste the code from your other activities where you don't want the home button to go back to main.

Also, if you want the home button to not do anything when you're in the main page, then simply don't set an `onClickListener`. If you set a listener and define an `intent` to go `MainActivity`, then of course it'll keep going to main...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to define your main activity's launch mode to be [`singleTop`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). That way you won't get the weird "main -> main -> main" sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much.I test to use result is when stay on main and click the button all will be close.